# Why does the desnity plots exceed the unity value in the hist(x,freq="FALSE") command of R?

Tags: r, probability-density, kernel-density

I am using hist(x_new,freq = FALSE) command to plot  histogram, but the probability density exceed the value unity.

Comment: A code example and screenshot of your plot would be helpful.

Comment: A [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is needed if others are to provide a meaningful answer to this question.

Comment: I am new to this site and this is my first ever question. I also tried to but add the screen shots  the  site wasn't accepting the question.  please remove the downvotes, it would be much appreciable.

Comment: I got the answer from  https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996248/john-coleman .  It is the area which should be unity, not necessarily the values on y axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probability *density* is not the same thing as probability. Densities are not in general bounded by 1. The point is that the total *area* under the density is 1, which is completely consistent with portions of it being above 1. In fact, it is quite common for a density function (or density histogram) to be above 1 in some places.

Comment: agreed.   could you please mention how can I get the parameter of the kernel density estimate in R The command is hist(data)  and density(data)

Comment: @VijayKumar Type `?density` at the console. R help files are very informative (for most functions) and typically have detailed descriptions of the parameters and references to sources which describe the implemented algorithm.